# Sibling in other European languages

Tags: historical-linguistics

The English word sibling comes from sib + ling.  According to the OED the etymology of sib is:

> Etymology: Old English sib(b , = Old Frisian (and Frisian) sib ,
>   Middle Dutch sib(be , zibbe , Old High German sippi (Middle High
>   German sippe ), Gothic (un)sibjis . With the noun uses compare Old
>   Frisian sibba , sibbe , Middle Dutch sibbe , etc., Old Saxon sibbio
>   (Middle Low German sibbe ), Old High German sippo (German sippe , sipp
>   ) kinsman.

Are there another other equivalents of the word sibling in other European languages which come from the same root?  The German word "geschwister" for example seems to come from  Middle High German geswister, from Old High German giswestar which is a different root as far as I can tell.

In fact I am not even sure which other European languages have a word for sibling. It seems that French does not but Danish has "søskende".

Comment: did you mean root?

Comment: If you want a random example, sibling is "sourozenec" in Czech (West Slavic, similarly súrodenec in Slovak and Sorojenec in Slovenian). This word is composed of sou-rozen-ec, and literally means something like a co-birther. As an answer says, Slavic languages including Czech use the old root in "sebe/sobě" (self).

Comment: Modern WF has "sibbe (N) (kinsman)", "besibbe" (related: e,g. "Frysk en Ingelsk binne besibbe talen" (Frisian and English are related languages) ,"sibskip". No word like "sibling" exists though.

Comment: Could you explain what "WF" is?

Comment: @Lembik West Frisian

Answer (score 3):

The English *sibling* is [ultimately derived](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Sibling) from the Proto-Indo-European **s(w)e-bh(o)*, an enlargement of the root **swe-* "self" and is related to the second element in the English word [*gossip*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gossip&allowed_in_frame=0).

Slavic languages have words which are also derived from the PIE **s(w)e-bh(o)*, for example, Russian has the root *seb-* ("себ-") also meaning "self" (для себя - 'dlya sebya' - "for oneself"). There is also an adjective *sobstvenny* ("собственный") - '(one's) own' formed from another variant of the root, **sob-*.

Answer (score 2):

German has the word *Sippe*, meaning *tribe* or *kinfolk* (in a broader sense), nowadays probably mostly used as a deprecative word for someone's family, which has the same root as English *sibling*:

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sippe):

> From Old High German *sibba*, *sippa*, from Proto-Germanic * *sibjō*. **Cognate to English *sib***.